# OKTA REST API - Change user password who is connected with Active Directory

Tags: rest, active-directory, okta

I have an Okta account. And I have configured it with Active directory. I have imported several users from Active directory to Okta.

Now, I have a PHP site and I have created custom login form. Upon login form submission, I am checking username and password against Okta users via REST API. I am able to GET user information. All is well till now.

Now, I am supposed to work on reset password feature. I got REST API to trigger forgot password request via Okta API (for example: https://xxxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/authn/recovery/password).

The problem is here: Okta API does not allow me to trigger forget password request because the user account profile is mastered by Active Directory.

Is there any way that I can still manage user profile by Active Directory and be able to reset user passwords by Okta API?

PS: Below is my Forget password REST API call to Okta:

**URL**: `https://xxxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/authn/recovery/password`

**Header:**

```
Accept: application/json

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: SSWS AGoodApplicationTokenWorksFine
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "username": "abcd@gmail.com",
  "relayState": ""
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "errorCode": "E0000034",
  "errorSummary": "Forgot password not allowed on specified user.",
  "errorLink": "E0000034",
  "errorId": "oae6jL5WFCqTYi-TNqAwCx_VA",
  "errorCauses": [
    {
      "errorSummary": "Recovery credential not set."
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Under Directory Tab -> Directory Integrations -> Clicking on your AD -> Settings -> Import and Provisioning: Sync Password. Do you have this enabled?

Answer (score 0):

As per error, you are required to setup the "recovery question" to perform the call. Please make sure you setup a security question and try.